# Linked List Head C++

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I am making a simple linked list for a data structures class and am having trouble understanding how the head pointer is supposed to work.

I have

```
template <typename E>
class SSLL{
template<typename E>
        struct Node {
            E data;
            Node* next;
        };
public:
template <typename E>
    SSLL();
    void push_front(E element);
private:
    Node<E> * head;
    Node<E> * tail;
};
template <typename E>
SSLL<E>::SSLL() {
    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;
}
template <typename E>
void SSLL<E>::push_front(E element) {
    Node<E> * n = new Node<E>;
    n->data = element;
    n->next = head;
    head = n;
    if (!tail) {
        tail = n;
    }
}
```

However, doesn't this make head the first element in the list instead of a pointer to the first element.

I tried to do change push_front(E element) to this but am getting null pointer errors.

```
template <typename E>
void SSLL<E>::push_front(E element) {
    Node<E> * n = new Node<E>;
    n->data = element;
    n->next = head->next;
    head->next = n;
    if (!tail) {
        tail->next = n;
    }
}
```

All the examples I find online have head = n, but I still have trouble understanding why it is like that instead of head->next = n.

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you need to step through your code with the debugger line by line to get a grasp what's going on.

Comment: Another great tool for debugging linked lists is the pen and paper. I kid you not. Draw the sucker. Draw in the nodes. One change at a time, reconfigure the list to the new configuration the list should be in after the operation. Compare what you did to visualize the transformation of the list to that you are doing in the code and adjust the code accordingly.

Comment: Great. That's much easier to read. Ask yourself what happens with `head->next` on the first insert to the list when `head` is `NULL`?

Comment: I recommend you get a better data structures book or resource.

Comment: Always get your linked lists and other programs working without templates.  Converting a working linked list to using templates is simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most forms of linked lists, the head pointer points to the first node in the list or is null:

```
         +---+     +---+     +--+  
head --> | A | --> | B | --> |/0|  
         +---+     +---+     +--+  
                     ^  
                     |  
tail ----------------+
```

Many beginners confuse a list with a node.  A node is the object containing the data.  A list is a collection of nodes.

**Pushing at the head**
Inserting at the front requires the following steps:

1. Making the new node point to the head node.
2. Changing the head node to point to the new node.

1) Making new node point to head node:

```
         +---+  
p_new -->| C |
         +---+  
           |  
           V  
         +---+     +---+     +--+  
head --> | A | --> | B | --> |/0|  
         +---+     +---+     +--+
```

2) Making the head point to the new node:

```
         +---+  
p_new -->| C |  
head  -->|   |
         +---+  
           |  
           V  
         +---+     +---+     +--+  
         | A | --> | B | --> |/0|  
         +---+     +---+     +--+
```

In C++, this would look like:

```
Node * p_node = new Node;
p_node->next = head; // Step 1.
head = p_node; // Step 2.
```

Answer (score 0):

We can make new Head in c++ by simple code :

```
ListNode* dummy = new ListNode(0);
dummy->next = head;
```